# Find all overlapping circles in a spatial index

Tags: database, location, geospatial

Positions reported by phones are approximate - they contain a point (long, lat) and a radius - that is, a phone doesn't know where it is but does know it is within some distance of a certain point.

How can I store this in a database?  How can I retrieve all those phones within a certain radius of some other point?

(I have looked at MySQL's point-type but MySQL doesn't seem to like circles and doesn't seem to have even a `DISTANCE` function; are there other databases that do this well and fast?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you store the phones in a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). Then when you want to query a point, you can do an exhaustive search of only the phones nearby, and save time by not considering the ones too far away. I don't know of any normal database application that will do this for you, but it shouldn't be too difficult to implement yourself.

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing it in app-code.  Shame its not in normal off-the-shelf databases.  Here's a blog post about it http://williamedwardscoder.tumblr.com/post/23662033005/bounds-vs-points-in-spatial-indexes